# How to add a custom page with a Random product in PWA

Tags: graphql, pwa

**Hello everyone,**

Could you please share with me the code or a comprehensive tutorial on how to add a custom page with random products in a Progressive Web App (PWA) using GraphQL?

**Thank you.**